# Unexpected thread contention in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have tried to implement the following algorithm using `Parallel.Foreach`. I thought it would be trivial to make parallel, since it has no synchronization issues. It is basically a Monte-Carlo tree search, where I explore every child in a parallel. The Monte-Carlo stuff is not really important, all you have to know is that I have a method which works a some tree, and which I call with `Parallel.Foreach` on the root children. Here is the snippet where the parallel call is being made.

```
    public void ExpandParallel(int time, Func<TGame, TGame> gameFactory)
    {
        int start = Environment.TickCount;

        // Creating all of root's children
        while (root.AvailablePlays.Count > 0)
            Expand(root, gameInstance);

        // Create the children games
        var games = root.Children.Select(c =>
        {
            var g = gameFactory(gameInstance);
            c.Play.Apply(g.Board);
            return g;

        }).ToArray();

        // Create a task to expand each child
        Parallel.ForEach(root.Children, (tree, state, i) =>
        {
            var game = games[i];

            // Make sure we don't waste time
            while (Environment.TickCount - start < time && !tree.Completed)
                Expand(tree, game);
        });

        // Update (reset) the root data
        root.Wins = root.Children.Sum(c => c.Wins);
        root.Plays = root.Children.Sum(c => c.Plays);
        root.TotalPayoff = root.Children.Sum(c => c.TotalPayoff);
    }
```

The `Func<TGame, TGame>` delegate is a cloning factory, so that each child has its own clone of the game state. I can explain the internals of the `Expand` method if required, but I can assure that it only accesses the state of the current sub-tree and game instances and there are no `static` members in any of those types. I thought it may be that `Environment.TickCount` is making the contention, but I ran an experiment just calling `EnvironmentTickCount` inside a `Parallel.Foreach` loop, and got nearly 100 % processor usage.

I only get 45% to 50% use on a Core i5.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common symptom of GC thrashing.  Without knowing more about what your doing inside of the Expand method, my best guess is this would be your root-cause.  It's also possible that some shared data access is also the culprit, either by calling to a remote system, or by locking access to shared resources.

Before you do anything, You need to determine the exact cause with a profiler or other tool.  Don't guess as this will just waste your time, and don't wait for an answer here as without your complete program it can not be answered.  As you already know from experimentation, there is nothing in the `Parallel.ForEach` that would cause this.

Comment: What would be your recommended approach for profiling here? I've never done contention profiling before and the VS2012 profiler shows just too much data that I can't skim quickly to the bottleneck. In the performance profiler it shows me a quick view of the most expensive functions and calls, but I found nothing like that for the contentio n profiler. Thanks in advance.